# FTP server connection simulation

Tags: ftp, connection, simulation

How can I write a script or otherwise simulate about 100 
users connection to my own ftp server?

Comment: There exist stress test web services for testing services, but in any case your question is offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare a simple Java code.

First, you have to decide how these requests arrive to your server. I.e., completely random, one per minute, following a normal distribution or more likely an exponential distribution.

Then, you have to use a thread that has:

1. A method to make an ftp connection (e.g. **ftpCall()**)
2. A method to get the **x** milliseconds to the next FTP call (e.g. **getTimeToNext()**)

After an FTP call, the method has to stay in sleep for **x** milliseconds before to make the next call. Here is the outline of the code in Java

```
public class FTPTest{
  class MyFTPThread{
      private int numberOfCall=100;

      private void ftpCall() {
        //DO CONNECTION
      }


      private long void getTimeToNext() {
        //RETURN A RANDOM TIME OR A FIXED VALUE
      }

      public void run(){
        int counter = 0;
        while(++counter <= numberOfCall){
          ftpCall();
          this.sleep(getTimeToNext());
        }
      }
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    MyFTPThread t = new MyFTPThread();
    t.start();
  }
}
```